# Why does text seem a little blurry when I switched from DisplayPort to HDMI?

Tags: display, hdmi, external-display, displayport

I recently switched to another laptop that doesn't have a miniDisplayPort, only USB Type-C. I haven't got the adapter for type-C yet so I'm using an HDMI cable to connect to my monitor (2560*1440,60Hz) for now. My HDMI version is 2.0 so it should be identical to my previous laptop's miniDisplayPort. However, the text, especially when browsing the web, seems a little less crisp than before. UI elements and images are fine. Why is that the case? I tried adjusting the ClearType settings but it didn't help.
Video cards:
Old laptop: AMD Radeon HD 7970m, Intel HD Graphics 4000
New laptop: Nvidia Geforce GTX 970M, Intel 530

Comment: Why do you think the blurriness has something to do with the switch from DisplayPort to HDMI? You also switched everything else (except the monitor), right?

Comment: Yes, but I guess switching from an old high-end graphics card to a new one shouldn't alter the display quality?

Comment: But you didn't just change the card either. You changed *everything*, right? You changed the CPU, the OS installation, maybe even the OS version. You changed display settings. What didn't you change, other than the monitor?

Comment: I'm using the default Windows 10 display settings. Other things have changed but shouldn't affect text rendering.

Comment: As david said, you've changed far more than just the connector. This could easily be graphics card/driver related as well. Until you can test the same monitor with both technologies on the same machine, there are other variables that could be making a difference. Even then, dp and hdmi are different signals, and the graphics card could be outputting them differently.

Comment: Did you already check your dispaly settings (right mouse-click on your Desktop -> Display settings)?
There is an option called "Change the size of text, apps, and other items". It should be set to 100%